# Consolidating multiple properties files referenced by Spring

Tags: java, spring, properties

My Spring config looks like this:

```
<jee:remote-slsb id="ejb1"
    jndi-name="org.example.Ejb1"
    business-interface="org.example.Ejb1"
    environment-ref="ejb1Properties">
</jee:remote-slsb>
<util:properties id="ejb1Properties" location="classpath:ejb1.properties"/>

<jee:remote-slsb id="ejb2"
    jndi-name="org.example.Ejb2"
    business-interface="org.example.Ejb2"
    environment-ref="ejb2Properties">
</jee:remote-slsb>
<util:properties id="ejb2Properties" location="classpath:ejb2.properties"/>
```

... because the two EJBs may use different JNDI URLs, different context factories and authentication credentials. ejb1.properties and ejb2.properties have properties of the same name, with different values:

```
ejb1.properties:
  java.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
  java.naming.provider.url=t3://example1:7101
  java.naming.security.principal=id1
  java.naming.security.credential=foo

ejb2.properties:
  java.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
  java.naming.provider.url=t3://example2:7101
  java.naming.security.principal=id2
  java.naming.security.credential=bar
```

However, I would like my users to have one properties file to maintain, not two.

Clearly it's easy to write a startup script that generates ejb1.properties and ejb2.properties from a core properties file. But is there a way to have Spring get properties from a single file, mapping the names appropriately?

Comment: not unless you do it programmatically, I suppose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, there is nothing in Spring that handles your situation.  However, one straight forward solution would be to extend PropertiesFactoryBean and override the mergeProperties() method.  Here is an example of such a extension that filters property entries based on a name prefix:

```
public class FilteringPropertiesFactoryBean extends PropertiesFactoryBean {

    private String namePrefix;

    @Override
    protected Properties mergeProperties() throws IOException {
        Properties unfilteredProperties = super.mergeProperties();

        Properties filteredProperties = new Properties();

        // iterator over keys
        // discard entries whose key doesn't start with prefix
        for (Object key : unfilteredProperties.keySet()) {
            String name = key.toString();

            // trim the property name by removing the target prefix.
            String trimmedName = trimName(name);
            if (trimmedName != null) {
                // add the property to the filtered collection
                String value = unfilteredProperties.getProperty(name);
                filteredProperties.setProperty(trimmedName, value);
            }
        }

        return filteredProperties;
    }

    public void setNamePrefix(String value) {
        this.namePrefix = value;
    }

    private String trimName(String name) {
        // does name start with the prefix and is the name longer than the prefix
        if (name.startsWith(namePrefix) && name.length() > namePrefix.length()) {
            return name.substring(namePrefix.length());
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Configuring the factory bean would be something like:

```
<bean id="ejb1Properties" class="example.FilteringPropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="location" value="classpath:merged.properties"/>
  <property name="namePrefix" value="ejb1."/>
</bean>
```

With the above configuration and a merged.properties file containing:

```
ejb1.java.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
ejb1.java.naming.provider.url=t3://example1:7101
ejb1.java.naming.security.principal=id1
ejb1.java.naming.security.credential=foo

ejb2.java.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
ejb2.java.naming.provider.url=t3://example2:7101
ejb2.java.naming.security.principal=id2
ejb2.java.naming.security.credential=bar
```

The resulting properties returned by FilteringPropertiesFactoryBean#mergeProperties() is (note the prefix is stripped from the final property names):

```
java.naming.factory.initial = weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url = t3://example1:7101
java.naming.security.principal = id1
java.naming.security.credential = foo
```

Comment: I like this approach. Thanks.